# PTIJ: How can I tell if my cat is Jewish?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I suspect that my cat might be Jewish, but I'm not sure. I do have several reasons for my suspicion. He seems to love my sforim and will consistently sit on top of them when they are left out. If I try to read a sefer, he will often jump into my lap and sit between me and the page, so he can see it. He clearly prefers my kosher fish to his food which lacks hashgacha. Every Shabbos, he naps in the afternoon. He has even shown fascination with my tzitzis. Finally, he has never asked me for a cheeseburger.

I would love to determine once and for all if he is a Jew. How can I tell?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Is his mom Jewish?

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm not sure. He was a rescue.

Comment: Does he like eating goats? And does he spell his name with a kuf or a kaf?

Comment: @Ze'ev Are most cats in the neighborhood Jewish?

Comment: @Ze'ev male or female cat?

Comment: Does he cover his droppings? If not, check his yichus. He might not be a cat.

Answer (score 10):

By definition, felines are all Jewish. The name "cat" is just an abbreviation, כ״ט, meaning כהן טהור. This is why we don't allow cats to serve us in any way and they always must get first pick of the food by meal times.

Answer (score 3):

One way to test things is to see if your cat will eat *chametz*. We know that one criteria of discovering if something is chametz or not is if the food is *rauy le'achilat kelev* - if the food is fit to be eaten by a dog.

Well - dogs eat dog food. But, will your cat eat the dog food? If it doesn't, then your cat is Jewish!